# How to find a child element in protractor?

Tags: node.js, protractor

I have a parent element called by xpath and I want to get its child elements through a CSS class, I am getting the following error: `Failed: element(...).element.all is not a function`

I am trying to get the items as follows:

```js
var licenses_grid = await element(
 by.xpath(browser.params.constants.GENERALPATHS.LICENSES.LICENSESGRID)
).element.all(by.className('ui-grid-cell-contents ng-binding ng-scope'));
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need to `await` when declaring an element variable

Try this:

```
var parent = element(by.xpath(browser.params.constants.GENERALPATHS.LICENSES.LICENSESGRID));
var child = parent.all(by.className('ui-grid-cell-contents ng-binding ng-scope'));
```

Comment: @MarioRamosGarcía you only need to `await` it if you're going to wait for a promise to get resolved; in the `child` var you are just declaring the element. You would need it if you were to do something like `var childCount = await child.count();`

Answer (score 1):

You should use the shorthand notation instead. `$` for `element(by.css())` and `$$` for `element.all(by.css())`. You also don't need `await` here.

Your code should be something like this:

```
var licenses_grid = element(
  by.xpath(browser.params.constants.GENERALPATHS.LICENSES.LICENSESGRID))
    .$$('.ui-grid-cell-contents.ng-binding.ng-scope'));
```